# Frontend tool to manage H2 database

Tags: database, h2, database-administration

How to use [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/)'s integrated managment frontend?

For operations such as create table, alter table, add column, and so on.

Comment: See the H2 web site for a list of [Database Frontends / Tools](http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools).

Comment: More appropriate place for this Question is on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). But there you must outline specific criteria for what you mean by “the best”.

Comment: See Wikipedia: [*Comparison of database tools*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I like [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), and [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) is [very useful](https://netbeans.org/features/ide/database.html); but more often, I just fire up the built-in [`org.h2.tools.Server`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html) and browse port 8082:

```
$ java -cp /opt/h2/bin/h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server -help
Starts the H2 Console (web-) server, TCP, and PG server.
Usage: java org.h2.tools.Server 
When running without options, -tcp, -web, -browser and -pg are started.
Options are case sensitive. Supported options are:
[-help] or [-?]         Print the list of options
[-web]                  Start the web server with the H2 Console
[-webAllowOthers]       Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-webPort ]       The port (default: 8082)
[-webSSL]               Use encrypted (HTTPS) connections
[-browser]              Start a browser and open a page to connect to the web server
[-tcp]                  Start the TCP server
[-tcpAllowOthers]       Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-tcpPort ]       The port (default: 9092)
[-tcpSSL]               Use encrypted (SSL) connections
[-tcpPassword ]    The password for shutting down a TCP server
[-tcpShutdown ""]  Stop the TCP server; example: tcp://localhost:9094
[-tcpShutdownForce]     Do not wait until all connections are closed
[-pg]                   Start the PG server
[-pgAllowOthers]        Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-pgPort ]        The port (default: 5435)
[-baseDir ]        The base directory for H2 databases; for all servers
[-ifExists]             Only existing databases may be opened; for all servers
[-trace]                Print additional trace information; for all servers
```

Comment: In 1.4, you run the console with `java -jar /opt/h2/bin/h2.jar`.

Comment: Also consider `java -cp /opt/h2/bin/h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell`.

Answer (score 33):

How about the [H2 console application](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console)?

Comment: +0 e.g. `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Console`

Comment: Console application is great and can be accessed over http: http://localhost:8082/

Comment: Under eclipse (if you have the H2 dependency, via maven for example) open the class `org.h2.tools.Console` then right click and "run as Java Application"

Answer (score 20):

I use [sql-workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) for working with H2 and any other DBMS I have to deal with and it makes me smile :-)

Comment: I am using it with derby

Comment: It needs 32-bit Java installed in your system

Answer (score 13):

I would like to suggest [DBEAVER](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) .it is based on eclipse and supports better data handling

Answer (score 7):

one discuss found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/h2-database/0tFdTh6bZkk/_vcScTArZtcJ)

quote from Thomas Mueller:
    http://www.dbsolo.com/
    http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/
    http://executequery.org/index.jsp
    http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/index.html
    http://sql-workbench.net/index.html
    http://www.squirrelsql.org/

Answer (score 7):

There's a shell client built in too which is handy.

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
```

http://opensource-soa.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/how-to-use-h2-shell.html

```
$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -help
Interactive command line tool to access a database using JDBC.
Usage: java org.h2.tools.Shell <options>
Options are case sensitive. Supported options are:
[-help] or [-?]        Print the list of options
[-url "<url>"]         The database URL (jdbc:h2:...)
[-user <user>]         The user name
[-password <pwd>]      The password
[-driver <class>]      The JDBC driver class to use (not required in most cases)
[-sql "<statements>"]  Execute the SQL statements and exit
[-properties "<dir>"]  Load the server properties from this directory
If special characters don't work as expected, you may need to use
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 (Mac OS X) or CP850 (Windows).
See also http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Shell.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it, but [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/screen_shots.html) [looks](http://www.razorsql.com/images/razorsql/main45.png) pretty good.

Comment: And it is not free. "The download expires 30 days after the first use. After the expiration, a registration code / serial number
must be purchased to continue using RazorSQL. "

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Jetbrain's IDE: DataGrip https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: Its not free, it comes with 30 days trial

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it as an embedded database in spring I use the following configuration to enable the built in web client when the main app is running:

```
<!-- Run H2 web server within application that will access the same in-memory database -->
<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="h2WebServer">
    <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,-tcpPort,9092"/>
</bean>
<bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8082"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use DbVisualizer a lot for H2-db administration.

There exists a free version:

https://www.dbvis.com/download/