# Is there a way to use commandline within a JFrame GUI?

Tags: java, swing

So, I made a jar file which runs a class that has JFrame, panel and a button.
Once the button is clicked it runs the main method of my class
that runs a method with parameter(String s);

I would like this parameter to change depending on the user's needs.

For example, if clicking the button shows a message s,

I would like the user to type in the message that they want.

So if they type in hi, they would get hi, on their screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've been trying to do what Sanjay has told me. but it seems I can't add a TextListener to the jtextField. so how could i get the text

Answer (score 2):

Use a `jtextField` to get the user input and use the `gettext()` to get value entered in  `jtextField` and use this to show message.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can obtain the parameter `s` as a [command line argument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760887/frontends-tool-to-manage-h2-database/2761825#2761825).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't add a `TextListener` to the `JTextField`. So how could I get the text?

You can add an `ActionLIstener` to your `JTextField` like they show in the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and other [examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html#eg).